# Table Alignment First Row Level

Tags: tables

I have some issues with the alignment of my first row. I want it all to be at the same level.

My code:

```
\begin{table}[htb]
  \centering
  \caption{References of Questions}
  \begin{tabular}{|p{3cm}|p{20cm}|}
    \hline\rowcolor[gray]{0.8}\color{black}
    Construct         & Source of Questions \\\hline

    A & Self-developed. \\\hline
    B & Self-developed. \\\hline
    B & Self-developed. \\\hline

  \end{tabular}
  \label{tab:Definitions}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There's no reason to issue `\color{black}`. Try removing it and the output will be as expected.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering

\caption{References of Questions}
\label{tab:Definitions}

\begin{tabular}{|p{3cm}|p{8cm}|}
\hline
\rowcolor[gray]{0.8}
Construct         & Source of Questions \\
\hline
A & Self-developed. \\
\hline
B & Self-developed. \\
\hline
B & Self-developed. \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you really need to change color in a `p` column, precede the color command with `\leavevmode`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering

\caption{References of Questions}
\label{tab:Definitions}

\begin{tabular}{|p{3cm}|p{8cm}|}
\hline
\rowcolor[gray]{0.8}
\leavevmode\color{blue!70}
Construct         & Source of Questions \\
\hline
A & Self-developed. \\
\hline
B & Self-developed. \\
\hline
B & Self-developed. \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Notes

1. Never forget the `p` option
2. The `\label` is better placed near the `\caption`.

Answer (score 2):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\caption{References of Questions}
\label{tab:Definitions}
\begin{tblr}
{
colspec = {Q[l,m]X[l,m]},
row{1}  = {bg=gray8!60},
hlines,vlines,
}
Construct & Source of Questions \\
A         & Self-developed.     \\
B         & Self-developed.     \\
B         & Self-developed.     \\
\end{tblr}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[h]
\caption{References of Questions}
\label{tab:Definitions}
\begin{tblr}
{
colspec    = {Q[l,m]X[l,m]},
row{1}     = {bg=gray8!60},
cell{1}{1} = {fg=blue},
hlines,vlines,
}
Construct & Source of Questions \\
A         & Self-developed.     \\
B         & Self-developed.     \\
B         & Self-developed.     \\
\end{tblr}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[h]
\caption{References of Questions}
\label{tab:Definitions}
\begin{tblr}
{
colspec = {Q[l,m]X[l,m]},
row{1}  = {bg=gray8!60,fg=blue},
hlines,vlines,
}
Construct & Source of Questions \\
A         & Self-developed.     \\
B         & Self-developed.     \\
B         & Self-developed.     \\
\end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1, but you may show that coloring text is simpler and doesn't make any problems (for example: `fg=blue` as shown in egreg answer).

Comment: @Zarko Thanks. I have updated.